# ios5 notifications alert style

Tags: notifications, ios5

Is there any way to set the alert style for notifications via programming in ios5?

My app uses notifications that have actions and I do not want to put those notifications as banners. The flow of the app is dependent on the push notifications that arrive.

So I was finding a way by which I could set the alert style of the notifications to "Alerts" rather than "Banners". Any way to do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, your app cannot control this. It is up to the user to decide how he wants your notifications to display. But why does it bother you? Clicking on the action button (aka "View") or clicking the notification itself in Center is similar in behavior regarding your app's code.

Comment: If user does not open the notifications that arrive as banners, then I am in trouble. When they come as alerts, user has to click Yes or No.

Comment: When they come as alerts, the user has the option to click the action button (like "View" or "Open") or click close. If he clicks close, your app doesn't get notified, so it is exactly the same as if he saw the notification but didn't click on it.