# Notification center alert style

Tags: iphone, ios, notifications, nsnotificationcenter

How to change your iPhone or iPad Notification Center alert style via programming? because in notification center the "banner" alert style is default so is it possible to set alert style to alerts or none via programming?
I have also refered [ios5 notifications alert style](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7951478/ios5-notifications-alert-style)

but I am not able to get that answer. Thanks in advance.

Comment: no way to do that  via programming

Comment: adali, thanks for your reply. That means User have to set alert style  by selecting the app from the notifications setting right?

Comment: yes , only can change the setting in System Setting page

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8229385/set-default-ios-local-notification-style-for-application